# CSV file link not getting read by .get in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, csv, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing a webscraper that is supposed to scrape all the links that are in a .csv file. When I try to use the .get from Selenium to retrieve the link from the CSV file it doesn't get parsed to the .get and the webpage never gets loaded in the browser. This is my code that I'm having problem with :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import csv

with open('links.csv') as read:
    reader = csv.reader(read)
    link_list = list(reader)
    with open('ScrapedContent.csv', 'w+', newline='') as write:
        writer = csv.writer(write)
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        path = "/home/Projects/SRealityContentScraper/chromedriver"
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        i = 1
        while i < len(link_list):
            try:
                driver.get(link_list[i])
            except Exception:
                continue
            information_list = wait.until(ec.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ng-binding")))
            information_list = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1.page-title span.text.ng-binding")))
            title = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h1.page-title span.text.ng-binding")
            information_list = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.switcher.ng-binding.ng-scope span.ng-binding.ng-scope")))
            offers = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.switcher.ng-binding.ng-scope span.ng-binding.ng-scope")
            information_list = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr.c-aginfo__table__row td.ng-binding")))
            addresses = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("tr.c-aginfo__table__row td.ng-binding")
            number_wait = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.value.link.ng-binding.ng-scope")))
            phone_number = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.value.link.ng-binding.ng-scope")
            phone_number.click()
            phone_number = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.phone.ng-binding")
            mail_wait = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.value.link.ng-binding")))
            email = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.value.link.ng-binding")
            email.click()
            email = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.value.link.ng-binding")
            print(title.text, " ", offers.text, " ", addresses.text, " ", phone_number.text, " ", email.text)
            writer.writerow([title.text, offers.text, addresses.text, phone_number.text, email.text])
            i+=1


        driver.quit()
```

The first webpage from the links.csv file is [https://www.sreality.cz/adresar/mm-reality-praha-nove-mesto/1019]. The scraper is supposed to get this link in the .get request but it never does so and gets stuck on "data:," in the url bar. There is about 10 links so far that are present in the CSV file. My question is why doesn't the URL get parsed to the .get request? What am I doing wrong? I have been trying to figure this out for hours now and can't seem to understand why would this happen...

Comment: Print out link_list[i] to see if it's a string.

Comment: print(link_list[i] prints out the following output : 

['https://www.sreality.cz/adresar/fincentrum-reality-praha-smichov/10762']

Now I don't understand even more what's wrong... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is actually turning the iterator into a list. So you're actually creating a list of the rows of the CSV when you do this:

```
reader = csv.reader(read)
link_list = list(reader)
```

If we look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html we'll see

> Each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings.

So you actually want code like this:

```
reader = csv.reader(read)
rows = list(reader)
for row in rows:
    print(', '.join(row))
    print("url equals: " + row[0]) #assuming it's the first (or only element of the csv row)
```

Comment: I have applied the solution and it worked. Thank you for explaining this to me!

Comment: @541daw35d if the answer worked, please select it as such.

Answer (score 0):

your code looks kinda strange
i would loop through `link_list`:

pseudo-pythoninsh-code:

```
read your file
set up driver
for link in link_list:
     driver.get(link)
     do your stuff
     write your file
quit driver
```

Comment: I did as suggested and I agree that it is indeed a better solution. Unfortunately this raises an error :

selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'url' must be a string

Now I get what the error is saying but I don't understand how exactly is the CSV content not a string... Each link is in the first column one after the other so I don't get why isn't considered a string. Do you have any idea as to why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this out myself, it seems like `link_list = list(reader)` returns a list within a list. I was able to get it to work with `driver.get(link_list[0][i])`.

Answer (score 0):

reader here is just a list of rows, it means list of lists,
so you can access easily your links like below:

```
reader = csv.reader(read)
for r in reader:
    print(r[0])
```

You can check Automating the boring stuff with Python, great book